# TileMill: Export to folder structure for tile server

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

How do I export my map as a folder structure?

What I would like:

```
.../Map/z/x/y.jpg
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean TileMill instead of MapTiler (both exist, but you tagged this with TileMill), the answer would be to use [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to export your produced MBTiles as single image files on-disk.

Answer (score 0):

MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com) exports such directory structure directly.

If you render with MapTiler into MBTiles format or prepare the maps in TileMill, then the `mbutil` utility is able to make the export into the directory structure on the command line.